# Angular JS - model not updating number input field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following, and I'm sure there's some simple solution here that I'm just overlooking.  I'm loading data into the model, but it's not updating the input field.

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Testing</h2>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  From: <input name="Price" type="number" ng-model='object.number["From"]' /> 
  To: <input name="Price" type="number" ng-model='object.number["To"]' />
  </div>
</div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.object = {number : {}};
    $scope.object['number'] = {From: null, To: null}
    console.log($scope.object['number']);

    $scope.loadPrice = function(){
        $scope.object['number'].From = "5";   
        $scope.object['number'].To = "5";   
    }

    $scope.loadPrice();
    console.log($scope.object['number'])

}
```

Included the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pCnfH/6/

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're constraining the input to be of `type="number"` but setting the value to a string: `$scope.object['number'].To = "5";`

So you either want to set the values to numbers:

```
$scope.object['number'].From = 5;   
$scope.object['number'].To = 5;
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pCnfH/7/)

Or remove the number constraint: [that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pCnfH/8/)

Comment: Thanks. Quite an oversight on my part.